# Visual Studio Community 2019 on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: visual-studio, ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have install VirtualBox on Ubuntu and I want to install Visual Studio on that virtual machine. After I downloaded the file from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ I tried to install VS, but I couldn't. A dialog box shows up and wrote: "This product is not supported on this version of Windows. Try upgrading Windows."
How can install Visual Studio Community/Professional on Ubuntu???

Comment: What version of Windows is running in the VM?

Answer (score 1):

MSVS feels when windows is a guest over linux host.

When I was interested in visual studio inside linux environment i was tricking with making  VBox  VHD windows installation at windows host, then copy the vhd to linux VM with the VHD with already installed MSVS.

And that was working for all MSVS versions. But it is not a very interesting due to a fact that DX DRAW or DX SHOW or  low-level DX API was not  worked at  virtual videoadaptor.

So, a better way is  multiple OS with RDP ( Remmina ) access to real windows OS from Linux. VS CODE is just editor, not a toolchain.

Answer (score -2):

I do not understand right your question. You have Ubuntu installed and you want to install VS in the virtual machine because you didnt make it within Ubuntu?

**For the Virtual Machine:**
First make sure that you have a licenced windows installation on the virtual machine. 
Then please proceed and make sure that you have the version needed from windows. As this thread mentions (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/555107/this-product-is-not-supported-on-this-version-of-w.html) mentions

> We require this because Visual Studio 2019 needs the .NET desktop runtime 4.7.2, which is only available on 1703 and higher for Windows 10 .

**For Ubuntu:**
Installing VS on Ubuntu shouldn't be any problem.
Download the required installation from https://code.visualstudio.com/Download 
Install VS with sudo dpkg -i [FileName].

Comment: Visual Studio is Windows only, it is Visual Studio *Code* that is cross platform. Editions only exist for Visual Studio.